# amcharts hideGraph vs graphs.hidden

Tags: javascript, amcharts

```
chart = initialiseGraph();
chart.graphs.forEach(function(elm){
 elm.hidden=true;
});
chart.validateNow();
```

and

```
function handleLegendClick( graph ) {
  var chart = graph.chart;
  for( var i = 0; i < chart.graphs.length; i++ ) {
    if ( graph.id == chart.graphs[i].id )
      chart.showGraph(chart.graphs[i]);
    else
      chart.hideGraph(chart.graphs[i]);
  }
  // return false so that default action is canceled
  return false;
}
```

What are the differences between these two codes and performance wise which one is better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `showGraph`/`hideGraph` methods has the same effect as calling `validateNow` after each call which redraws the entire graph completely after each call, whereas setting the `hidden` property does nothing until you call `validateNow` to update the chart.

In a looping situation, modifying the `hidden` property on multiple graphs first before calling `validateNow` once at the end of the loop is significantly faster than calling the show/hide method at each iteration.

Comment: I don't see in the source code that `showGraph`/`hideGraph` methods call `validateNow()` method internally at all. They both call `initChart()` at the end. (**v 3.21.4**)

Comment: While technically correct, `initChart` is an internal method that is not meant for end users (if it's not mentioned in the AmCharts documentation, it's not a public method). The point is that it is effectively the same as (or *similar* if you really want to argue semantics) as calling the validate methods. Calling out an internal method doesn't really add anything to the answer, so relating the methods to a public method makes talking about how they work easier.